# Magento 2 - MySQL privilege error on module install

Tags: magento2.2, aws, mysql-triggers

I am getting the following error when installing a module on AWS.

```
General error: 1419 You do not have the SUPER privilege and binary logging is enabled (you *might* want to use the less safe log_bin_trust_function_creators variable), query was: CREATE TRIGGER newsletter_subscriber_updated_at_before_insert BEFORE INSERT ON newsletter_subscriber FOR EACH ROW SET NEW.magemail_updated_at = CURRENT_TIMESTAMP;
```

I am using AWS RDS.

Is there a work around for this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to check if RDS MySQL has triggers disabled or enabled, because the latest gen of RDS MySQL has triggers disabled and you have to enable these.

Also check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11601692/mysql-amazon-rds-error-you-do-not-have-super-priviledges) post to how to set pervillages and triggers in RDS Web console.